# How do I display data using the url

Tags: php, mysql, database

How do I display the information data using the ID in the url

example is www.thatsite.com/?id=1092

and it will display the data of the 1092 ID

```
<?php    
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "xxxxxxx", "xxxx","xxxx");
    $query = "SELECT `name`, `age`, `xxxxx` , `xxxxx`, `image` FROM `profiles` WHERE `id` = $id LIMIT 1";
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query,$id);
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
        echo $row['name'];
        echo $row['xxxx'];x
        echo $row['age'];
        echo $row['xxxxxxx'];
        echo $row['image'];
      }  
?>
```

Comment: [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is full of security holes. It is prone to sql injection, xss attack, csrf, html injection.

I have re-written it to circumvent all the issues.

**1.) Sql Injection** is now mitigated using prepare queries

**2.) Html injection** is mitigated using **intval** for integer variables and **strip_tags** for strings. you can read more about data validations and sanitization in php to see more options available

**3.) xss attack** has been mitigated via **htmlentities()**.
you can also use **htmlspecialchars()**. Read more about all this things

see better secured codes below

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "ur dbname";

// Create connection
$connect = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($connect->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $connect->connect_error);
}

// ensure that the Id is integer using intval
$id = intval($_GET["id"]);

// if id is a string. you can strip all html elements using strip_tags
//$id = strip_tags($_GET["id"]);

//Avoid sql injection using prepared statement

// prepare and bind

$stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT name, age , xxxxx, image FROM profiles WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1");

// id is integer or number use i parameter
$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);

// id is integer or number use s parameter
//$stmt->bind_param("s", $id);

$stmt->execute();
$stmt -> store_result(); 
$stmt -> bind_result($name, $age, $xxxxx, $image); 
while ($stmt -> fetch()) { 

// ensure that xss attack is not possible using htmlentities
    echo "your Name: .htmlentities($name). <br>"; 
    echo "your age: .htmlentities($age). <br>"; 
    echo "your xxxxx: .htmlentities($). <br>"; 
    echo "your image name: .htmlentities($image). <br>"; 

}


$stmt->close();
$connect->close();
?>
```

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use `die($connect->connect_error);` in your code, because it could potentially leak sensitive information. See this post for more explanation: [mysqli or die, does it have to die?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15320411/1839439)

Comment: Yes I know that. Its just for debuging and testing purposes. the rules is to disable and remove all error notices in production. am aware of that. thanks for pointing out

Comment: You could simply replace it with `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` since it is not clear it was meant for debugging only. The error reporting can be switched on in production.

Answer (score 0):

from https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

leave out the 'get id', the id is in the SQL:

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
```

The similar example at 
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {

    echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```